# How to get static properties from static class using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

I've got a static class with static getters.

```
public static class Cars
{
   public static KeyValuePair<Guid, string> Acura
   {
       get { return new KeyValuePair<Guid, string>(new Guid("MMMMMMMM-509B-477A-ADB1-5CD014B41001"), "Acura"); }
   }
   public static KeyValuePair<Guid, string> AlfaRomeo
   {
      get { return new KeyValuePair<Guid, string>(new Guid("MMMMMMMM-509B-477A-ADB1-5CD014B41002"), "Alfa Romeo"); }
   }
   // etc.
}
```

I need to retrieve all the static properties from this static class and do something with each KeyValuePair. But the following throws a System.FormatException at runtime saying that it could not find recognizable digits

```
Type type = typeof(Cars);
foreach(var manufacturer in type.GetProperties())
{
    if(manufacturer.PropertyType == typeof(KeyValuePair<Guid, string>))
    {
        var v = manufacturer.GetValue(null, null); //this does not work
        // How to get the KeyValuePair<Guid, string>? 
    }
}
```

How to get each KeyValuePair?

UPDATE: Sorry.. the solution works perfectly, the problem is that GUID are not valuid Guids.. M is not hexadecimal character

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This does not have to do anything with reflection or static properties. Within the getters of your properties there are exceptions thrown.

`"MMMMMMMM-509B-477A-ADB1-5CD014B41001"` and `"MMMMMMMM-509B-477A-ADB1-5CD014B41002"` are no valid `Guid`s. Create `Guid`s with valid values and the properties won't throw the exceptions.

Each of the digits in a `Guid` must be a hexadecimal digit (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Format)).

```
new Guid("MMMMMMMM-509B-477A-ADB1-5CD014B41001")
```

will throw the exception, while for example

```
new Guid("00000000-509B-477A-ADB1-5CD014B41001")
```

won't.

Comment: Fridays.. 
sorry about that and thanks for your time. I hadn't realised the issue was that

Comment: @iberodev Fridays. That. Have a nice weekend ;)